# need a cast syntax to access an old c api

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a glue function between two data types and I can't seem to get the compiler to be happy.  On one side, I have a pointer to a chunk of data that is logically a n x 2 array, but is declared as:

```
double* pData=new double[2*n];
```

On the other side, I have a c function that is declared as

```
void Function(double data[][2], int n);
```

If I remember my c syntax, the data[][2] is really just a pointer to a contiguous chunk of memory, but the compiler knows the size of the second dimension is 2.  So I'd like to take pData and pass it into Function(), without a memcpy.  I just can't seem to write the cast.  I thought something like

```
Function((double [][2])pData,n)
```

would work, but the compiler (MSVC 8) doesn't like that.  Can anyone let me know the proper way to write the cast to get the compiler to be happy.

Comment: double data[][2] is double**, while your pData is double*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void Function(double data[][2], int n);
double* pData = new double[2*n];
Function((double (*)[2])pData, n);
```

Function parameters of the form `T[]` are identical to `T*` (not even `T* const` that some people expect).  This is a special case for parameter types in both C and C++.  So your `double[][2]` follows this rule, with T being `double[2]`.  Typedefs help illustrate this:

```
typedef double T[2];
void Function(T data[], int n);
// identical to:
void Function(double data[][2], int n);
// also identical to:
void Function(double (*data)[2], int n);
```

So you write `T*` when T is `double[2]` as `double (*)[2]`.

---

You could also do this:

```
void Function(double data[][2], int n);
double (*pData)[2] = new double[n][2];
Function(pData, n);
```

Which requires no cast because pData is already the correct type.  Or with typedefs:

```
typedef double T[2];
T* pData = new T[n];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to spell it out, Andrew's answer

```
Function(&pData, n)
```

doesn't work, you get:

```
error C2664: 'Function' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'double **' to 'double [][2]'
```

Roger Pate's compiles, the syntax without typedefs is this:

```
Function( (double (*)[2]) &pData, n);
```